# После глагола "полагается" ставится глагол совершенного или несовершенного вида?

Tags: глаголы

После глагола "полагается" когда употребляются глаголы НСВ и когда - глаголы СВ?

После "не полагается" употребляются глаголы НСВ или СВ?

Comment: "Полагается" и "не полагается" - это не два разных глагола, а один и тот же глагол, употребленный с частицей "не" и без нее.

Comment: @М_Г ну не будьте столь строги. У человека явно русский не родной. Вы бы исходный вариант посмотрели... Я уже на удаление ставить хотел, потом сообразил о чем речь.

Comment: Русский не мой родной язык!!!! Пишу статью и сравниваю этот глагол с его эквивалентами в персидском языке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После "полагается" и "не полагается" теоретически могут использоваться глаголы обоих видов, речь идет**о частотности употребления**.

**1) После сочетания "не полагается" практически всегда используется форма несовершенного вида**, а совершенный вид применяется крайне редко, в единичных случаях,  что видно и **по вопросу**: не полагается (что делать, а не что сделать).

**Вносить поправки** в канонические тексты **не полагается**, [И. Сокольский. 2006]. Ему вообще **не полагается знать** моих душевных переживаний. [Татьяна Тарасова, (1984-2001)]

«Ишь, ― подумал, ― и голос же у моей Марьи, всё видит, и **сесть** тебе **не полагается**!..» [А. М. Ремизов. Зайчик Иваныч (1906)]

2) **После глагола " полагается" также чаще используется  несовершенный вид**, но иногда встречаются глаголы совершенного вида. Можно задать вопросы "полагается что делать и что сделать".

То, что **полагается узнавать** всю жизнь, за один урок не узнать. [Булат Окуджава. (1962)]. Он задавал вопросы, и Чуйков отвечал, как и **полагается отвечать** на вопросы старшего начальника. [Василий Гроссман.  (1960)]

Я его продал за свою жизнь, здесь **полагается сказать** ― жалкую, за свою жалкую жизнь, за свободу и деньги. [Герман Садулаев.  2010]. Я знал, что мне сейчас **полагается пошутить,** а мне хотелось с ходу заныть: "Любимая, желанная, счастье моё, на всю жизнь. [Василий Аксенов.  1973]

Comment: Не решился править описки. Должно быть : **1) После  сочетания "не полагается"  2) После глагола "полагается"**

Comment: Спасибо, Вы очень внимательны и при необходимости всегда меня поправляете.

Answer (score -3):

Это глагол в современном русском довольно редок. Вместо ***полагается "то-то" и то-то"*** обычно используют ***"положено"***. А "полагаться" можно только на ***кого-то***.

> После глагола "полагается" когда употребляется глагол НСВ и когда - глагол СВ?

Грамматика не ограничивает. Чаще, наверное, несовершенного вида. Если вам нужно выразить с помощью глагола несовершенного вила, то можете использовать его.

*По внутреннему распорядку всем полагается выходить на перекличку.*
*По внутреннему распорядку всем полагается выйти на перекличку.*

Оба варианта возможны.

> После глагола "не полагается" глагол употребляется в НСВ или СВ?

Аналогично.

*По внутреннему распорядку не полагается сидеть днем на койке.*
*В нашем театре актерам не полагается уйти со сцены и не вернуться.*

Второй пример несколько искусственный, но в принципе возможен. Вам лучше, думаю, этот вариант не использовать.

Все четыре примера, как сказал, допускают замену "полагается" на "положено".

Comment: *Это глагол в современном русском довольно редок*. Товарищ @Мимоходов, не вводите людей в заблуждение. Тем более тех, для кого русский не родной.

Comment: Cерж я не смог вам ответить, но это не моя вина. Модератор так решил, хотя я его не понимаю, я специально. удалил исходное сообщение ради того, чтобы обсудить причины. В целом - спасибо за замечания, но я с ними совершенно не согласен.

Comment: @Мимоходов если вы хотите, что-то обсудить, плодить одинаковые ответы не стоит. Можно воспользоваться чатом. https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=rus.stackexchange.com